# VBA - Error Handling for Creating New Sheets Based on File Names

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I got the code below to create and name worksheets according to files in a folder:

Link: [Creating Worksheets based on Filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509661/creating-worksheets-based-on-filenames)

```
Sub test()
  Dim Filenames As Variant, strFilename As Variant, strPath As String
  Dim i As LongPtr

  strPath = "D:\myPath"
  strFilename = Dir(strPath & "\" & "*.xlsx")
  Do Until strFilename = ""
    Filenames = Filenames & "|" & strFilename
    strFilename = Dir
  Loop

  Filenames = Mid(Filenames, 2)
  Filenames = Split(Filenames, "|")  ' <- all .xlsx filenames in this array

  For i = LBound(Filenames) To UBound(Filenames)
    with Worksheets.Add 
      .name = Left(Filenames(i), Len(Filenames(i)) - 5)
    end with
  Next i

End Sub
```

However, I now require Error Handling for:

1) If the sheet name already exists

2) To exclude certain files in the directory by file name - This isn't such a huge issue, but if it can be done that would be really great

Here is some code for the first problem - but I don't know how to implement it as the parameters are a string:

```
Function sheetExists(sheetToFind As String) As Boolean
    sheetExists = False
    For Each Sheet In Worksheets
        If sheetToFind = Sheet.Name Then
            sheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next Sheet
End Function
```

Here is some code for the second problem:

```
For i = LBound(Filenames) To UBound(Filenames)

        Do While Filenames <> "test.xlsx"

            With x.Worksheets.Add
            .Name = Left(Filenames(i), Len(Filenames(i)) - 5)
        Loop

    End With

    Next i
```

With either the `Do While` or `If Else` Statement, I keep getting the error:

> Loop without Do While

or

> End If without Block If

or

> Else Without If

I have posted this question at the below 2 links as well:

http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1785646

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29091353/Creating-Worksheets-based-on-Filenames.html?anchor=a42513369&notificationFollowed=205670107#a42513369

Comment: you have `Do While` and `With` but you are closing `Loop` and `End With`, it needs to be `End With` and then `Loop`

Comment: Instead of `Do While Filenames <> "test.xlsx"` you should use a `if` statement `If Filenames(i) <> "test.xlsx" Then` then your `With` block and then `End If`

Comment: Hi Peh, yes this did work thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are after the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim strFilename As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim WB As Workbook

Set WB = ThisWorkbook ' define which workbook you want to add the sheets
strPath = "D:\myPath\"
strFilename = Dir(strPath & "*.xlsx")

Do Until strFilename = ""
    strFilename = Split(strFilename, ".")(0)

    ' check is strFilename already exists in existing sheets

    If sheetExists(strFilename) = False Then ' doesn't exist
        WB.Sheets.Add(After:=WB.Sheets(WB.Sheets.Count)).Name = strFilename
    Else
        ' just raise a message box
        MsgBox "Worksheet " & strFilename & " already exists.", vbInformation
    End If
    strFilename = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

---

```
Function sheetExists(sheetToFind As String) As Boolean

    sheetExists = False
    For Each Sheet In Worksheets
        If sheetToFind = Sheet.Name Then
            sheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next Sheet

End Function
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you @Shai Rado